# Large File transfer from Flex client to C++ server through UDP

Tags: c++, apache-flex, air, udp

I am trying to build a UDP application(P2P) of Large file transfer in Flex. My back end is C++. How can I transfer my client's files to server without any middle server. If I use stratus services..how to connect that to C++. Please help me, if possible with source code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you choose to use UDP for a large file transfer?

Comment: Hi Starkey,UDP is the best way that I know which transfers large files in rapidly.It is faster than TCP file transfer. In UDP, we can send data in packets. If u know any alternative please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the FTP protocol.
This problem has already been solved.